# SQLAlchemy one to one relationship across multiple tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationships

I have been trying to model a relationship between four tables, where entries from table A can be linked to entries in the other three tables. For example:

```
Table A (components)
id     brand     status
N1     br3       free
N2     br2       used
N3     br2       used
N4     br3       used
N5     br2       used

Table B (device1)
id     comp1     comp2
2      N2        N3

Table C (device2)
id     comp1     comp2
6      N4        N5

Table D (device3)
id     comp1     comp2
```

I can link the component from the device table like so:

```
class Device1(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comp1 = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey('components.id'), unique=True) 
    comp2 = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey('components.id'), unique=True)
```

But how do I implement a relationship for all three tables from table A?
I was looking for something like `component.deviceinstalled` which would return the device that the component is attached to, regardless of which table it belongs to (B, C or D), for instance:

```
component1 -> <N2  br2  used>
component1.deviceinstalled -> <2  N2  N3> from table B

component2 -> <N4  br3  used>
component2.deviceinstalled -> <6  N4  N5> from table C
```

Comment: Can you clarify the last table?
Why don't you make one table, to store say the name plus the unique id, then link all the other tables to that id?

Comment: The last table is empty, but is exactly like table B and C. Could you please elaborate on your suggestion? Do you mean an intermediate look-up table to see on which table the component is assigned ?

Comment: If you want an extensive explanation check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form

I am not sure I understand what you are doing but what I have is:
A main table with ids and names, say ANIMAL NAME/ANIMAL ID
Then tables linking other information to that main table, say:
ANIMAL ID/ANIMAL OWNER

Etc, this is done with the relationship in sqlalchemy (though depending on the version you use I know there are several ways),
So in your case I supose you could have something like (each row represents a table):
DEV NAME/DEV ID|
DEV ID/COMP1 |
DEV ID/COMP2 |
etc...

Comment: But my actual question is how to span a relationship on N tables. The structure I provided fits my data in the best possible (organization wise) way. Thanks for the suggestion though !